# Changing a class variable in a callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I'm new to typescript, but I think this is more of a javascript issue than anything else-- specifically, my lack of understanding of how to accomplish something.

I need to set a class-level variable in a callback and am not sure how to go about it.  In my typescript class I have a method with a fat arrow function.  It calls an object that makes an ajax request with a callback function.

In that callback I would like to set a value on the class.  In a nutshell, this is what I've got:

```
 class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {
 protected entity = new Entity();

 protected getToolbar() {
    toolbarbuttons.push({
        title: 'hello',
        onClick: () => { 
            outsideService.makeAjaxCall(
                {
                    url: 'somewhere_in_cyberspace'
                },
                function (response) {
                    this.entity.name = response.Name;
                }
            );
         }     
    });
  }
}
```

That code doesn't work as-is, because in the callback of course 'this' refers to Window and not my class.

Fair enough, and I've tried to do something along the lines of `_that = this` before my onClick handler, I can't get the response values to 'stick' after the handler exits, in the sense that in subsequent methods `this.entity.name` is not what the callback set it to?  Something I can do here or have I missed something?

Comment: Have you tried making the callback an arrow function? At the moment, the bit where `this.entity.name = response.Name` sits inside a `function` declaration, rather than something like `(response) => { ...`. That might be the issue

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd function also needs to be an arrow function:

```
class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {
    protected entity = new Entity();

    protected getToolbar() {
        toolbarbuttons.push({
            title: 'hello',
            onClick: () => {
                outsideService.makeAjaxCall({
                    url: 'somewhere_in_cyberspace'
                }, (response) => {
                    this.entity.name = response.Name;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This compiles into:

```
var MyClass = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyClass, _super);
    function MyClass() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.entity = new Entity();
    }
    MyClass.prototype.getToolbar = function () {
        var _this = this;
        toolbarbuttons.push({
            title: 'hello',
            onClick: function () {
                outsideService.makeAjaxCall({
                    url: 'somewhere_in_cyberspace'
                }, function (response) {
                    _this.entity.name = response.Name;
                });
            }
        });
    };
    return MyClass;
}(SomeOtherClass));
```

As you can see typescript translates the arrow function into a regular anonymous one but it saves a reference `var _this = this;` which is then used inside the most inner function.